# Entity Framework consuming a lot of memory (possible memory leak?)

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, iis, entity-framework-4, autofac

We are using EF4.3.1 in a WCF service ( our business \ application layer). We are using EF Code First with existing database and Fluent Mapping (EntityTypeConfiguraiton). 
An instance of DbContext is created for each request and then disposed off.

We have a generic repository which uses the DbContext.

When running on test servers we found that the Business layer app pool is going out of memory in 30 mins or so with 10 concurrent users. We took dump of the IIS worker process and found that EF is consuming a lot of memory, there were many object in on large object heap created by EF. We could see objects for data retrieved from th DB on the heap. Not sure if the DbContext dispose is taking care of this. The % time in GC was very high (> 16%).
One strange thing we noticed in the dump file was, there was a huge string object  (around 87MB) storing string representation of all my mapping files. I found this to be very strange,

Has anybody encountered any such memory leak issue with EF? Also please also let us know if there is something wrong in our usage of EF. Please let me know if more details are required.

Thanks
Prasad

**EDIT**
We inject an instance of DbContext using AutiFac DI (WCF integration). The life time for Dbcontext is InstancePerLifeTime ( one request per http request). We have implemented this way to share the instance of DbContext in all repositories instances in one HTTPrequest.

The way we access database is 
// declaration
IGenericRepository UserRepository {get;set;} // Property injection using AutoFac

// Usage
var user = UserRepository.FindBy(u => u.userid == "test@test.com");

We are not using explicit transactions in repositories.

Comment: Could you shows us example of how you're using some transaction with EF?

Comment: @Jorge , please find the EDIT to the original question.

Comment: We did some analysis on this, it appears operations like Sum \ Average through one to many relations causes slowness. We moved some of these operations to the stored procs and the performance improved. This also reduced memory pressure, we are still fine tuning will add comments based on our findings

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue when recursively querying a lot of records (millions) without disposing the `DbContext`.  With the state-less nature of WCF services, and because you are disposing of the 'DbContext', this likely is not your problem (unless each user is simultaneously pulling a lot of data into context in one method call).

Ensure that you have each block of database logic wrapped in a using statement.  This should allow the garbage collector to remove everything in context from memory.

For example:

```
public void MyWcfMethod()
{
    using(MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
    {
        // All calls to database go here.
    }
}
```

My only other thought would be that some other library in your service (automapper, etc.) still has a reference to the `DbContext` thereby preventing from going out of scope.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your reply, one question though, we use repositories and hence need to share the DbContext for HTTP request, not sure how can I use this. We have implemented Unit Of work using Autofac DI. Autofac injects the DbContext, I could verify that the Dispose on DbContext is getting called, before session ends. not sure why EF is still consuming this much memory - Prasad

Comment: DbContext is the only dependency I am not injecting with Autofac just to avoid that problem :)

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the automapper may still have a reference? Is this a known issue and solution for this?